# Mapnik Slow tile generation with i9-990K, 64GB ram and NVME SSD Database

Tags: mapnik, rendering

I have setup an OSM tile server following the guide at: https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts and https://github.com/giggls/openstreetmap-carto-de. My database is stored on a nvme drive and it should be reasonably fast but Postgres takes all the CPU resources, reads lots of data but the tile generation is painfully slow. It takes upwards of 1000 seconds to generate a single tile around zoom level ~10.

**My current postgres config**:

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 6GB
effective_cache_size = 18GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 500
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 15728kB
min_wal_size = 4GB
max_wal_size = 8GB
max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 4
```

**tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep " TILE "**:

```
Jul 23 11:28:46 .. .. DEBUG: DONE TILE ajt 6 16-23 32-39 in 7.494 seconds
Jul 23 11:28:49 .. .. DEBUG: START TILE ajt 5 16-23 16-23, age 8.77 days
Jul 23 11:28:51 .. .. DEBUG: START TILE ajt 6 32-39 24-31, age 8.76 days
Jul 23 11:28:51 .. .. DEBUG: START TILE ajt 6 24-31 24-31, age 8.76 days
Jul 23 11:28:52 .. .. DEBUG: DONE TILE ajt 5 16-23 16-23 in 2.667 seconds
Jul 23 11:28:58 .. .. DEBUG: DONE TILE ajt 6 24-31 24-31 in 7.131 seconds
Jul 23 11:29:06 .. .. DEBUG: DONE TILE ajt 6 32-39 24-31 in 14.688 seconds
Jul 23 11:30:19 .. .. DEBUG: START TILE ajt 8 136-143 88-95, age 8.76 days
Jul 23 11:30:22 .. .. DEBUG: START TILE ajt 9 272-279 168-175, age 8.75 days
Jul 23 11:30:23 .. .. DEBUG: START TILE ajt 9 264-271 176-183, age 8.75 days
Jul 23 11:30:23 .. .. DEBUG: START TILE ajt 9 272-279 176-183, age 8.75 days
Jul 23 11:30:29 .. .. DEBUG: DONE TILE ajt 9 272-279 168-175 in 6.654 seconds
Jul 23 11:30:29 .. .. DEBUG: DONE TILE ajt 9 272-279 176-183 in 5.516 seconds
Jul 23 11:30:30 .. .. DEBUG: DONE TILE ajt 8 136-143 88-95 in 10.702 seconds
Jul 23 11:30:32 .. .. DEBUG: DONE TILE ajt 9 264-271 176-183 in 8.223 seconds
Jul 23 11:30:47 .. .. DEBUG: START TILE ajt 10 536-543 344-351, age 8.07 days
Jul 23 11:30:47 .. .. DEBUG: START TILE ajt 10 528-535 344-351, age 8.09 days
Jul 23 11:40:59 .. .. DEBUG: DONE TILE ajt 10 528-535 344-351 in 611.975 seconds
Jul 23 11:41:08 .. .. DEBUG: DONE TILE ajt 10 536-543 344-351 in 620.976 seconds
Jul 23 11:41:48 .. .. DEBUG: START TILE ajt 11 1072-1079 688-695, age 8.03 days
Jul 23 11:41:48 .. .. DEBUG: START TILE ajt 11 1064-1071 688-695, new metatile
```

**top -n 1** during tile generation:

```
Tasks: 232 total,   3 running, 132 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.5 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 65875956 total,   504024 free,  9029780 used, 56342152 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 67043324 total, 67042300 free,     1024 used. 49666720 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 4489 postgres  20   0 6697132 6.141g 6.113g R  87.5  9.8  79:09.95 postgres
 4490 postgres  20   0 6734652 6.167g 6.113g R  87.5  9.8  61:42.98 postgres
  139 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   6.2  0.0 106:56.70 kswapd0
    1 root      20   0   77912   2768    432 S   0.0  0.0   0:17.18 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.18 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:08.37 kworker/0:0
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
```

System specs:

```
CPU1: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9900K CPU @ 3.60GHz (Cores 16)
    Memory:  64338 MB
    Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1024 GB (=> 953 GiB)\
    Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 1024 GB (=> 953 GiB)
    Disk /dev/sda: 10000 GB (=> 9314 GiB)\
    Disk /dev/sdb: 10000 GB (=> 9314 GiB)\
    Total capacity 20 TiB with 4 Disks
```

both drives are configured in RAID-1.

Where should I look next if I want to narrow down the issue? are my postgres configs correct for this system?

---

**Extra Details:**

**Quick Installation Steps (skipping the basics)**:

```
createuser renderaccount
createdb -E UTF8 -O renderaccount gis
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
ALTER TABLE geometry_columns OWNER TO renderaccount;
ALTER TABLE spatial_ref_sys OWNER TO renderaccount;


# install dependencies ...
# install mapnik-german-l10n for transalations
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install pythainlp

sudo apt install postgresql-plpython3-10
sudo apt install postgresql-plpython-10


cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/giggls/mapnik-german-l10n.git
cd mapnik-german-l10n
sudo make
sudo make install

# create 
CREATE EXTENSION osml10n CASCADE;
CREATE EXTENSION osml10n_thai_transcript CASCADE;
CREATE EXTENSION osml10n_thai_transcript CASCADE;
CREATE EXTENSION osml10n_thai_transcript CASCADE;
CREATE EXTENSION osml10n;
```

Postgres Config for Import

```
shared_buffers = 14GB
work_mem = 1GB
maintenance_work_mem = 8GB

effective_io_concurrency = 500
max_worker_processes = 8
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 8

checkpoint_timeout = 1h
max_wal_size = 5GB
min_wal_size = 1GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9

random_page_cost = 1.1
min_parallel_table_scan_size = 8MB
min_parallel_index_scan_size = 512kB
effective_cache_size = 22GB
```

Import Command

```
osm2pgsql -d gis -G -S /home/sbw/src/openstreetmap-carto-de/hstore-only.style --hstore --tag-transform-script /home/sbw/src/openstreetmap-carto-de/openstreetmap-carto.lua -C 64000 --number-processes 8 -p planet_osm_hstore /home/sbw/data/planet-latest.osm.pbf --flat-nodes /osm-flatnode/flatnode.file --slim

#process log:
Processing: Node(5285996k 2901.2k/s) Way(587621k 60.52k/s) Relation(6855940 754.31/s)  parse time: 20620s
Node stats: total(5285996269), max(6580810624) in 1822s
Way stats: total(587621865), max(700753265) in 9709s
Relation stats: total(6855996), max(9736741) in 9089s
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_hstore_polygon
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_hstore_roads
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_hstore_line
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_hstore_point
Stopping table: planet_osm_hstore_ways
Stopping table: planet_osm_hstore_nodes
Stopping table: planet_osm_hstore_rels
Building index on table: planet_osm_hstore_ways
Stopped table: planet_osm_hstore_nodes in 0s
Building index on table: planet_osm_hstore_rels
Stopped table: planet_osm_hstore_rels in 1651s
Copying planet_osm_hstore_roads to cluster by geometry finished
Creating geometry index on planet_osm_hstore_roads
Copying planet_osm_hstore_point to cluster by geometry finished
Creating geometry index on planet_osm_hstore_point
Creating osm_id index on planet_osm_hstore_roads
Creating indexes on planet_osm_hstore_roads finished
All indexes on planet_osm_hstore_roads created in 3553s
Completed planet_osm_hstore_roads
Copying planet_osm_hstore_line to cluster by geometry finished
Creating geometry index on planet_osm_hstore_line
Creating osm_id index on planet_osm_hstore_point
Creating indexes on planet_osm_hstore_point finished
All indexes on planet_osm_hstore_point created in 8629s
Completed planet_osm_hstore_point

Osm2pgsql took 35838s overall
node cache: stored: 5285996269(100.00%), storage efficiency: 83.17% (dense blocks: 728393, sparse nodes: 194148886), hit rate: 100.00%
```

Building indexes

```
psql -d gis -f osm_tag2num.sql
psql -d gis -f views_osmde/view-line.sql
psql -d gis -f views_osmde/view-point.sql
psql -d gis -f views_osmde/view-polygon.sql
psql -d gis -f views_osmde/view-roads.sql
./views_osmde/apply-views.sh gis en
psql -d gis -f indexes-hstore.sql
```